# How to get fullscreen texture coordinates for a fullscreen texture from a previous rendering pass?

Tags: three.js, webgl

I do two rendering passes in webgl application using three.js (contrived example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ggaJ8/)):

```
renderer.render(depthScene, camera, depthTarget);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

The first rendering pass is to the render target `depthTarget` which I want to access in the second rendering pass as a texture uniform:

```
uniform sampler2D tDepth;

float unpack_depth( const in vec4 rgba_depth ) { ... }

void main() {
    vec2 screenTexCoord = vec2( 1.0, 1.0 );
    float depth = 1.0 - unpack_depth( texture2D( tDepth, screenTexCoord ) );
    gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3( depth ), 1.0 );
}
```

My question is how do I get the value for `screenTexCoord`? It is not `gl_FragCoord.xy`.

To avoid a possible misunderstanding: I don't want to render the texture from the first pass to a quad. I want to use the texture from the first pass while rendering the geometry in the second pass.

**EDIT:**

According to the WebGL specification `gl_FragCoord` contains *window coordinates* which are *normalized device coordinates* (ndc) scaled by the viewport. The ndc are within [-1, 1] so the following should yield coordinates within [0, 1] for texture lookup:

```
vec2 ndcXY = gl_FragCoord.xy / vec2( viewWidth, viewHeight );
vec2 screenTexCoord = (ndcXY+1.0)/2.0;
```

But somewhere I must be wrong because the [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/ggaJ8/1/) does still not show the (packed) depth?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out myself. The correct way to calculate the texture coordinates is just:

```
vec2 screenTexCoord = gl_FragCoord.xy / vec2( viewWidth, viewHeight );
```

See a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ggaJ8/2/).